# Avoid edge duplicates in PostGIS

Tags: nodes, geospatial, postgis, spatial, edges

I would love to create edges between nodes between which distance smaller than 5m. The following PostGIS code works.

```sql
create table edges as
  select a.id from_gid, 
         b.id to_gid, 
         st_shortestline(a.geom_26916, b.geom_26916), 
         st_distance(a.geom_26916, b.geom_26916) as distance
  from flowers as a,
      (select * from flowers) as b
  where st_dwithin(a.geom_26916, b.geom_26916, 5);
```

Nevertheless, it gives me duplicates of edges. How can I modify the code to get unique edges? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same table is queried twice (as `a` and `b`), so it will return an edge between records 1 and 2, and a second line between records 2 and 1. It will also return strange result for the same record (a point).

You would need to add a filtering clause on id:

```sql
...
WHERE a.id < b.id AND st_dwithin(a.geom_26916, b.geom_26916, 5);
```